# How to view chromes' local storage data of previous installation for certain website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There was a website I used to note things online that required no login and recently I have reinstalled windows though i still have old program files.

[THIS](https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/notepad.html) is the the website now in current installation of chrome.

[image: screenshot of dev tools]

How can I access notepad_text section of previous installation from chromes' old user data? Is it even possible?

Please help.
Thank you.